# Jolt - Merge two arrays and rename fields

Tags: json, jolt

I have a problem writing objects to an array. Basically I want to merge the arrays and rename the fields, while keeping the objects seperately.

My input json looks like this:

```
{
   "board":[
      {
         "role":"Head of board", 
         "id":"111",
         "name":"John Snow"
      }
   ],
   "leaders":[
      {
         "role":"Accounting leader",
         "id":"222",
         "name":"Amanda Johns"
      },
      {
         "role":"HR leader",
         "id":"333",
         "name":"Frank Smith"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my spec: (I am aware that the values in brackets are probably not right)

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "board": {
        "*": {
          "id": "employees.bosses[#2].emp_num",
          "role": "employees.bosses[#2].position",
          "name": "employees.bosses[#2].name"
        }
      },
      "leaders": {
        "*": {
          "id": "employees.bosses[#2].emp_num",
          "role": "employees.bosses[#2].position",
          "name": "employees.bosses[#2].name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and this is my output:

```json
{
  "employees": {
    "bosses": [
      {
        "emp_num": ["111", "222"],
        "position": ["Head of board", "Accounting leader"],
        "name": ["John Snow", "Amanda Johns"]
      },
      {
        "emp_num": "333",
        "position": "HR leader",
        "name": "Frank Smith"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

while I expect output that looks like this:

```json
{
  "employees": {
    "bosses": [
      {
        "emp_num": "111",
        "position": "Head of board",
        "name": "John Snow"
      },
      {
        "emp_num": "222",
        "position": "Accounting leader",
        "name": "Amanda Johns"
      },
      {
        "emp_num": "333",
        "position": "HR leader",
        "name": "Frank Smith"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have major troubles understanding what to do and how the `[#n]` work, I would really appreciate any help with fixing my spec and explaination why this does/does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to distinguish the indexes of the arrays while combining them. To accomplish this, add a suffix letter or word(here I chose `a` for `a.[&1]`) for the first array while renaming all keys as desired within the first *shift* operation, then apply new extensions `employees.bosses` in the consecutive *shift* operation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "board": {
        "*": {
          "id": "a.[&1].emp_num",
          "role": "a.[&1].position",
          "name": "a.[&1].name"
        }
      },
      "leaders": {
        "*": {
          "id": "&1.emp_num",
          "role": "&1.position",
          "name": "&1.name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "employees.bosses"
    }
  }
]
```